# Switch Azure from dynamic to static IP address

Tags: azure, static-ip-address, dynamic-ip

How do I change my Azure website from using a dynamic IP address to a static IP address?

I want a static IP address that never changes.

I evidently do not have a virtual machine, as illustrated below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you using Azure App Service? If yes, what is the Pricing tier? Is it Free/Basic/Standard?

Comment: I'm new to Azure, so this may not answer your question... I am using App Service Pay-As-You-Go subscription.

Answer (score 1):

App Service is a PaaS (Platform as a Service) Offering. In PaaS, you don't have access to the server.

The Virtual Machine screenshot that you have shared in of Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS) type. So, App Services will not have IaaS - Virtual Machines and that's the reason why the VMs listing (in your question) is empty.

Now, coming to you question of a Static IP for your app. You can find it in the Custom Domains section of App Service as shown below.

[image]

And, this IP Address will change ONLY when you change (especially degrade from a higher tier to lower tier) the App Service Plan. If it doesn't change then you are lucky enough. But, Microsoft doesn't guarantee that it retains the IP Address if you change the App Service Plan's tier.

Another point to note is that you might see the same IP Address for another App Service too. that's completely fine and it works well even if you want to map your own domain to this App Service.

### Update:

When the App Service makes calls to another external end point, then it uses altogether another set of IP Addresses called Outbound IP Addresses which could be found in the Properties blade as shown below.

[image]

So, you need to share ALL the IP Addresses that are under **Additional Outbound IP Addresses** to the external WebService team for whitelisting. This way, your problem will be resolved.

Let me know of it makes sense now.

Update2:

For App Service, We can't create & assign a separate Static IP explicitly. If you need a static IP for some reason, then you have to choose Virtual Machines and then assign a Static IP Address to that VM and use the VM to deploy the Website.

Comment: The IP address you're showing above has changed several times in the past. It is evidently not static. Strangely, it is also not the IP address another web service says I'm using. I was shocked to learn this! What kind of trickery is this? Both this IP and the other IP bring up my website. I just want a static IP.

Comment: It's not possible to have a static IP address for Azure App Service. If you really want one, then create a Virtual Machine and assign a Static IP Address to it.

Comment: Ahh, so my service plan does not offer static IP addresses? But then you said I could get one by creating a VM. Is that the route you suggest?

Comment: I'm not suggesting to use VM as increases lot of maintenance at your end. Can you explain why you need a static IP address? Is it to setup DNS?

Comment: Why do we need a static IP? Our site connects to another web service that whitelists our IP. Problem is, our IP keeps changing, which "breaks" our connection to that service. They must discover our new IP though trial and error every nine months. To complicate this, the IP shown above is NOT the one we connect to them through. Again, I was shocked to learn that the IP shown above is different than our real one. This IP trickery and frequent change is causing a lot of trouble.

Comment: aah. Now, i understand why you are saying it's changing. Let me update the answer. I guess, you might have done some troubleshooing sessions with another web service and notieced that the IP Address is changing. Right? There is a reason for that. Azure App Service uses another set of IP Address called "Outbound Ip Address". Let me update the answer

Comment: This is a partial answer, and a good workaround. My conclusion is that my original question cannot be answered because my service plan does not allow static IP addresses. Therefore, we must resort to this workaround. I can accept that.

Comment: Yes. For App Service, you can't have a static ip. If you need a static IP, you have to choose Virtual Machines and then assign a Static IP Address.

Comment: Consider updating your answer to include this information. I did not know this until today. Thank you!